# Regexp .test always returns false

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

```
var str = "1405199610";
var re = new RegExp("\d{10}");
var myArray = re.test(str);
```

myArray gives false!

How is this possible? I tested this with online regex checkers and it checks out ok. When i try it in the console or jsfiddler, it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you type `new RegExp("\d{10}")` in the Chrome console, you will see that you expression becomes `/d{10}/`. Why? Because ``\`` is the escape character in strings and `\d` is an invalid escape sequence, so it becomes `d`. If you want to create a literal ``\`` you have to escape it ``\\``

Comment: `myArray` might be a bit of a misleading name for a variable that contains a boolean value!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var re = new RegExp("\\d{10}");
```

you need to escape the `\` when regexp is created by `RegExp()` object

See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

> ...Also do not forget to escape \ itself while using the new RegExp("pattern") notation since \ is also an escape character in strings.

Comment: thanks guys. I really need more experience with these things. They tend to be quite confusing!